# Validate HTML using PHP inbuilt Dom method

Tags: php, html, validation

I am using https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php to validate an HTML file. Below is the code. But every time I validate an HTML file, it says it's not valid. Is it an error with the code or is there any better PHP validators?

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('book.html'); // see docs for load, loadXml, loadHtml and loadHtmlFile
if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";
}
else
    echo "Its not valid";
?>
```

Comment: I think `validate` is more geared to validating xml rather then html. You could try `$dom->validateOnParse=true;` but I don't think you'll get much joy with the validate function as you currently have it

Comment: Ok. I have tried searching for other php html validators. But couldn't find any. Can't use any online api too

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys. Got that myself. Here is the code...

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = simplexml_load_string($html);
$xml = explode("\n", $html);
$flag=0;
if (!$doc) {
    $errors = array_reverse ( libxml_get_errors() );
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $flag++;
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}


function display_xml_error($error, $xml)
{
    $return  = $xml[$error->line - 1] . "\n";
    $return .= str_repeat('-', $error->column) . "^\n";

    switch ($error->level) {
        case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING:
            $return .= "Warning $error->code: ";
            break;
         case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR:
            $return .= "Error $error->code: ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL:
            $return .= "Fatal Error $error->code: ";
            break;
    }

    $return .= trim($error->message);

    if ($error->file) {
        $return .= "\n  File: $error->file";
    }

    return "$return\n\n--------------------------------------------\n\n";
}
if ($flag==0)
    echo "This document is valid.<br/>";
else
    echo "Its not valid html. Contains ".$flag." errors.<br/>";
```